# Why the extraneous horizontal padding inside button (Firefox only)?

Tags: html, css, firefox

**Code snippet ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1b1gdsk/)):**

```css
* {
    outline: none;
}

button {
    background: firebrick;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}

button > div {
    background: lightskyblue;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 60px;">
  <button>
    <div>label</div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Under Chrome, the left and right edges of the `button > div` are flush with those of the containing `button`; as a result, the `button`'s background is split into two non-contiguous regions, above and below the `button > div` element:

[image]

Under Firefox, however, this is not the case.  The `button > div` appears completely surrounded by the `button`'s background, just as it would if the `button`'s left and right padding (and/or the `button > div` left and right margins) had bee set to some value > 0.

[image]

Can someone tell me

> what other CSS setting can account for this extraneous padding/margin under Firefox?

(Note: by "other CSS setting" I mean one that is not explicitly set in the example's CSS.)

See working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m1b1gdsk/).

Comment: For starters I'd say because a button can't contain a div. Invalid HTML.

Comment: @j08691: +1 thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @SergeyDenisov: I'm usually not a fan of having my posts edited, but your edits to this one were excellent (and very instructive to me).  I really appreciate them.  Thank you!

Comment: @kjo thanks, I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this styles to fix it:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

**Code snippet ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/0a5Lqds8/)):**

```css
* {
    outline: none;
}

button {
    background: firebrick;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}

button > div {
    background: lightskyblue;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 60px;">
    <button>
        <div>label</div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'am disgusted and fascinated at the same time. well done :)

Comment: @NicoO why disgusted? =)

Comment: Let's say such selectors should not be necessary these days. I think the comment of @j08691 is important in this context. My comment was not meant to be offensive in any way.

Comment: @NicoO yes, I agree with you and I don't like to use browser-specific selectors, but sometimes we need it(. The problem isn't only with `<div>` inside, see [this article](http://davidwalsh.name/firefox-buttons).